# Running Python Script on My Server

Tags: python, server

I am trying to run this script on my server.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>'
print '</head>'
print '<body>'
print '<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>'
print '</body>'
print '</html>'
```

I have that code in a python file. I uploaded the file to cgi-bin folder. I then set permission's so every box was ticked (Full Permission). I then attempted to view the page. But I get the error below.

500: Internal server error

This error is generated when a script running on the server could not be implemented or permissions are incorrectly assigned for files or directories

Troubleshooting suggestions:

Temporarily disable any rewrite rules by renaming your .htaccess file if it exists.

Ensure that any CGI or Perl scripts have at least .755. permissions.

If trying to run PHP and you get this error, you may have an invalid php.ini in your /cgi-bin, or may be missing your php.dat file in this folder.

How can I fix this so I can start writing scripts an get on with my website?

All the code does is "Hello World", the script work on other servers. What has a php.dat got to do with me an my python. How am I meant to understand a PHP file when it's half in machine language.... E.g.

```
Ü™  ì™  ð™  ô™  ø™  ü™   š
  š
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is irrelevant in this case. It's mentioned in case you are using PHP, but you are not, so you can ignore it.

There are so many possible causes of this error so start at the beginning and work your way through.

First thing to check is the server error log files, if you have access to them they will likely reveal the problem straight away.

Next check whether your server is properly configured to run `.py` scripts as cgi. Also, check the cgi-bin directory permissions.

Verify that the python binary is located at `/usr/bin/python` on the server. BTW, a better alternative "shebang" is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

because it is less sensitive to path.

Errors in the code can also cause http 500. Your code works fine for Python 2. It's unlikely, but the server might be using Python 3?

Comment: I am still stuck on this problem, I just posted it, admin suspenped it. Can you help me debug this, what the F is wrong with admin on this site. Are they dumb

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the admin on this site - I don't think that they understood your question because of the rather unorthodox way you asked it. Anyway, see my additional answer for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

From the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27541761/21945) you say that you are using Python 3.4. The script that you show will run in Python 2, but not in Python 3 because the syntax of the print statement has changed - it is now a function.

To fix the script so that it will run in Python 3, change *all* of your print statements into functions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print('<html>')
print('<head>')
print('<title>Hello Word - First CGI Program</title>')
print('</head>')
print('<body>')
print('<h2>Hello Word! This is my first CGI program</h2>')
print('</body>')
print('</html>')
```

I have also changed the "shebang" at the top of the script to run whichever python is on the path.

If this doesn't fix the problem, look at the suggestions that I made in my previous answer, i.e. look in the server logs for errors, check your file and directory permissions, make sure that you are running the correct Python version etc.

Finally, talk to your hosting provider - I am sure that they can advise you how to set it up properly and there probably will be instructions on their site - find them and follow them.